# Error: C stack usage 7970592 is too close to the limit after log transformation in R

Tags: r

I tried to reduce skewness and kurtosis of my data so I ran a log transformation. However, it shows "Error: C stack usage 7970592 is too close to the limit" after log transformation.

Here is my code:

#### Checking normal distribution of NPS visit & social media post data

```
library(moments)

nps_post_visit <- na.omit(nps_post_visit)

nps_post <- nps_post_visit$post

nps_visit <- nps_post_visit$visit

kurtosis(nps_post,na.rm=T)

skewness(nps_post,na.rm=T)

kurtosis(nps_visit,na.rm=T)

skewness(nps_visit,na.rm=T)
```

#### log Transformation to reduce skeweness and kurtosis:

```
log.nps_post_visit <-log(1+nps_post_visit[,3:4])

log.nps_post_visit <- as.data.frame(t(log.nps_post_visit)) # Set transformed data as data.frame

newnps_post <- log.nps_post_visit$post

newnps_visit <- log.nps_post_visit$visit

kurtosis(newnps_post,na.rm=T)

skewness(newnps_post,na.rm=T)

kurtosis(newnps_visit,na.rm=T)

skewness(newnps_visit,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: can you provide some details about your dataset, like size, no. of columns and rows, variable type etc ?

Comment: Hi Neeraj, thanks for your comment. I deleted 'log.nps_post_visit <- as.data.frame(t(log.nps_post_visit))' and it works!